# Продолжение работы задачи с добавлением новых данных

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Имеется задача:

```
public async Task<IPageModel> LoadPageAsync(Uri pageUrl)
{
    IDocument document = await LoadStreamAsync(pageUrl);
    IElement content = document.QuerySelector("div#dle-content");
    IPaginatorModel paginator = GetPaginator(content.QuerySelector("div.navi"));

    PageModel result = new PageModel
    (
        new TaskCommand(async () => await LoadPageAsync(pageUrl)),
        paginator,
        await GetSerials(content)
    );

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Но я бы хотел в некоторых случаях продолжить заполнение результата, как пример подгрузить 2ю страницу в кэш. Что бы последующий запрос в обе стороны был кэширован. Т.е. при запросе 1й страницы, 2я попадала в кэш, и при ее запросе выдавался результат из кэша, при запросе 2й страницы подгрузилась вместе со 2й 3я, но была добавлена в результат и 1я, и 3я.

Могу ли я сделать так, что бы после того как задача отработает вернуть ее результат, но при этом запустить такую же задачу но которая просто прокэширует данные?

Т.е. сделать что-то на подобии такого:

```
protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await base.InitializeAsync();

    Task<IPageModel> result = _parserService.MakeCacheAsync(new Uri("/page/1/", UriKind.Relative));
    Page = await result;
    await result.ContinueWith(async task =>
        await _parserService.MakeCacheAsync(new Uri("/page/2/", UriKind.Relative)));
    await result.ContinueWith(async task =>
        await _parserService.MakeCacheAsync(new Uri("/page/3/", UriKind.Relative)));
}
```

Не повлияет ли это на результат?

Как лучше такое провернуть, т.к. то что я привел здесь замедляет работу всего приложения, т.к. по моему задача ждет окончания всех `ContinueWith`?

Comment: А зачем ждать, почему нельзя сразу три грузить?

Comment: @tym32167: Ну можно схлопотать например ошибку многоподключенных хостов с 1го айпи :)

Comment: `return await Task.FromResult(result);` ===> `return result;`?

Comment: То есть вам нужна очередь запросов на сервер?

Comment: А что мешает на стороне иметь фоновый Task, который мониторит какую-то конкурентную коллекцию в которую добавляют запросы на создание кеша?

Comment: Ну и как бы, вы и так ждете конца задачи, почему нельзя просто написать в три строки `await page1; await page2; await page3`?

Comment: @iluxa1810: вариант не плохой, но тогда придется клеить кнопку отмены кэширования.

Answer (score 1):

Самый просто вариант- это иметь в фоне `Task`, который обрабатывает элементы какой-нибудь конкурентной коллекции, иначе говоря типичный случай поставщик/потребитель.

Добавляете туда то, что нужно закешировать, а фоновый `Task` в свою очередь выполнит метод `MakeCacheAsync`.

В итоге, вы сразу вернетесь из метода `InitializeAsync` при получении первой страницы не дожидаясь обработки кеша.

> по моему задача ждет окончания всех ContinueWith

Когда вы вызываете `await`, то дожидаетесь результата => да.

Comment: Попробую такой вариант, отпишусь если что-то пойдет не так :)

Comment: единственное, можно попробовать из метода InitializeAsync убрать все лишние await и посмотреть, что будет. Сначала делаете ContinueWith без await, а в конце  Page = await result; . Не помню, как оно работает и будет ли в таком виде работать.